# NSDictionary allKeys order

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I need to display in a UITableView the content of a NSDictionary returned by an API, respecting the order of the keys.

I'm using :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSString *key = self.data.allKeys[indexPath.section];
        NSArray *list = self.data[key];
        id data = list[indexPath.row];

        PSSearchCell *cell = [PSSearchCell newCellOrReuse:tableView];

        cell.model = data;

        return cell;
}
```

but as I do `self.data.allKeys`, I'm loosing the order of my keys. I can't sort them by value as it doesn't concern them.

Comment: Those keys never where ordered. Dictionaries don't have an order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get Original order of NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386921/how-can-i-get-original-order-of-nsdictionary-nsmutabledictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone said, **I can't order my keys as they appear in my NSDictionary log** because a NSDictionary is not ordered.

I asked people from the API to return an array instead:

```
0 => name : key 1
     value : value 1

1 => name : key 2
     value : value 2
```

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

Too bad there isn't a method "sortedArrayUsingArray" used like that :

```
NSArray * arrayOne = [@"key E", @"key A", @"key C"];

NSArray * arrayTwo = [@"key A", @"key B", @"key C", @"key D", @"key E", @"key F"];

NSArray * orderedArray = [arrayOne sortedArrayUsingArray: arrayTwo];
```

Comment: No such method exists: "sortedArrayUsingArray". Use: http://blog.pioneeringsoftware.co.uk/2008/08/20/sorting-an-array-by-another-array/

Answer (score 26):

Try this,

```
NSArray *keys = [myDictionary allKeys];
keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
}];

NSLog(@"%@",keys);
```

Now fetch values based on the key sorted.

**EDIT**

To sort them in alphabetical order try this,

```
NSArray *keys = [myDictionary allKeys];
keys = [[keys mutableCopy] sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSLog(@"%@",keys);
```

Comment: But I don't have such thing as "Foo1", "Foo2"... I don't have any numbers in my key name. My API returns key = "Cinema" value = list of cinema, key = "Theatre" , value = list of theatre, and I need to display them in that order : Cinemas first, then theaters.

Comment: @βhargavḯ I don,t want to sort these keys where I want the keys should be received without changing order. So is it possible? please help.

Comment: @βhargavḯ Thanks.. Its working for numeric order for dictionary :)

Comment: use sortedArrayUsingSelector instead sortUsingSelector

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick method to take a source array (of objects that are all out of order) and a reference array (that has objects in a desired (and totally arbitrary) order), and returns an array where the items of the source array have been reorganized to match the reference array.

```
- (NSArray *) reorderArray:(NSArray *)sourceArray toArray:(NSArray *)referenceArray
{
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [referenceArray count]; i++)
    {
        if ([sourceArray containsObject:[referenceArray objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            [returnArray addObject:[arrReference objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    return [returnArray copy];
}
```

Note that this is very fragile.  It uses `NSArray`'s `containsObject:` method, which ultimately will call [`NSObject`'s `isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a).  Basically, it should work great for arrays of `NSString`s, `NSNumber`s, and maybe `NSDate`s (haven't tried that one yet), but outside of that, YMMV.  I imagine if you tried to pass arrays of `UITableViewCell`s or some other really complex object, it would totally sh*t itself, and either crash or return total garbage.  Likewise if you were to do something like pass an array of `NSDate`s as the reference array and an array of `NSString`s as the source array.  Also, if the source array contains items not covered in the reference array, they'll just get discarded.  One could address some of these issues by adding a little extra code.

All that said, if you're trying to do something simple, it should work nicely.  In your case, you just send `arrayOne` from the answer you posted as the source array, and `arrayTwo` as the reference array.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you were losing the order of the keys, so I suppose you pull those keys from a `NSArray`. Right? And in that `NSArray` you have the keys ordered as you want. And I also see that the objects of the `NSDictionary` are `Arrays`, right? Yes. So in your `Ordered Array` you have more arrays.

`data` is the name of the NSDictionary.

So, all you have to do is  to bring that `NSArray` (the one that is ordered as you always wanted) into this .m file and after that use some awesome code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You can do it by doing the following:

```
@interface yourViewController ()
{
    NSArray *yourArrayOrdered;
}
@end

@implementation yourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    yourArrayOrdered = [[NSArray alloc] initWith...:... ];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    NSString *key = yourArrayOrdered[indexPath.row];
    NSArray *list = [self.data objectForKey:yourArrayOrdered[indexPath.row]];

    //your code continues here...

    /*id data = list[indexPath.row]; //don't think you need this line

    PSSearchCell *cell = [PSSearchCell newCellOrReuse:tableView];

    cell.model = data; */

    return cell;
}
```

And this is all you have to do to keep the order you want using a NSDictionary and NSArray.

To visualize it better, in the case that your ordered array only contains strings it would be like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    NSString *key = yourArrayOrdered[indexPath.row];

    NSString *myString = [self.data objectForKey:yourArrayOrdered[indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"THIS IS THE OBJECT %@", myString];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AND THIS IS THE KEY %@", key];

    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps.