# How to prevent order changing in NSDictionary in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsurlconnection

Hi In my application I have a login screen where I have to post credentials to C# server.The order which I used is as such below

username 
password
domainname

```
Code:  

 NSDictionary*disPost=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"naresh",@"UserName",@"n123",@"Password",@"naresh-in",@"DomainName",nil];
```

I can able to post the data to server successfully but the credentials order is changing like below.

Password
UserName
DomainName

Due to this reason I am getting an exceptional error from server. Please help me to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386921/how-can-i-get-original-order-of-nsdictionary-nsmutabledictionary

Comment: the real issue here is, why does the server-side code require the information to be in a specific order? if each component of data is labeled (that is, they arrive as key-value pairs), the server should not care about order!

Comment: Why not fixing it in the place where it should be fixed? If the server is so sensetive to data order, I belive that's not correct.

Comment: You cant use NSDictionary like that. I dont know your situation maybe it will be silly but why dont you keep them in NSMutableArray ?

Answer (score 4):

NSDictionary has key-value pairs, it is not ordered. You need an array to keep the order of the elements. You could use 2 arrays (1 for keys the other for values) or use an array for keys (to know the order) and a dictionary for the key-value pairs.

Comment: even can be done in single array of actual values such as username or password. the parameter name can be added as "hardcoded" string while creating request or can be added using #define

Answer (score 2):

NSDictionary is not an ordered container. If you really want an ordered dictionary then use OrderedDictionay from,

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Comment: NSSet is also unordered.

Comment: ooops sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes me think that its not NSDictionary that you want to use, because with dictionaries you really shouldn't care about the order.

And I think the glitch in your code is probably with the part that sends to the server, try sending them separately, or use another datatype than NSDictionary.

good luck!